# Convert epoch time to gmt using mysql

Tags: mysql, utc, gmt

I am running into trouble converting a time to utc/gmt.

```
 select from_unixtime(1623167869);
 2021-06-08 11:57:49
```

GMT should return `2021-06-08 14:57:49`.

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(1623167869), 'SYSTEM', '+00:00')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FROM_UNIXTIME

The return value is expressed in the **session time zone**.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

```
> SET time_zone = '+00:00';SELECT @@SESSION.time_zone;select from_unixtime(1623167869);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

+---------------------+
| @@SESSION.time_zone |
+---------------------+
| +00:00              |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

+---------------------------+
| from_unixtime(1623167869) |
+---------------------------+
| 2021-06-08 15:57:49       |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

> SET time_zone = '-02:00';SELECT @@SESSION.time_zone;select from_unixtime(1623167869);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

+---------------------+
| @@SESSION.time_zone |
+---------------------+
| -02:00              |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

+---------------------------+
| from_unixtime(1623167869) |
+---------------------------+
| 2021-06-08 13:57:49       |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Comment: thanks, this option would work as well.  i wish they had an option to just pass in utc/gmt to a function. but mysql doesn't think it is needed.  read a long post with dev arguing with another user.